# yii2 - Should The Owner Of All The Yii2 Files Be 'root' or 'www-data'?

Tags: yii2

I'm facing few permission issues and that might be because of wrong user assigned to yii2 files. Currently, all the files and folders have 'root' as their owner, should it be 'www-data' instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `root` or `www-data`. It should be your dedicated user.

For example locally - `vagrant` (if you are using Vagrant), on production server - something like `hosting_omar_tariq` (name can vary depending on hoster policy).

Comment: Thank you, so I should believe that it wasn't the issue.